# Stacking footer DIVs with CSS

Tags: html, css

Looking for a specific stacking order inside a flex container.  Pretty basic footer split into 3 sections, so you have left and right Divs 100% height and 20% width. The middle would flex to fill the difference BUT middle needs to be split in half.  So top and bottom Divs inside at 50% height each.  I can’t seem to figure out the positions with absolute, fixed, ect. Or floating whatever works best.
Thanks

Ok sorry, here is the CSS inside flex container

```
.footer_left_box {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    left:0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#C9D329;
}
.footer_middle_top_box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color:#2BB851;
}
.footer_middle_bottom_box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color:#3954D4;
}
.footer_right_box {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#E33538;
}
```

This is an example of what I need

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. You must show what you have done by posting a complete example of your code **in the question itself**.

Comment: As Hunter said: To help you with your CSS we first need to see your ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) HTML and attempted CSS, so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Comment: @LeeAlexander share us the layout you want and your html code for reference

Comment: It won’t let me attach an image, which I have because Im not ranked 10.

Comment: Plus it wont let me add any more to my question. I am trying to add HTML code in comment section but doesn’t come out correctly

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that but you may need to adapt the structure.

```css
footer {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
}
.left,
.right {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}
.left {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
.right {
  background: #bada55;
}
.middle {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: #c0c0ae;
}
.bottom {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: #c0ffee;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: thank you Paulie_D I appreciate the answer and your time!